# Cannot create platform OpenGL context

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation

On my ubuntu 18.04, when I start android emulator:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd pixel
Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are 
enabled ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:66: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL 
context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))
```

Just standard Android workflow... I can't believe this is unic issue...

Comment: Same issue in Fedora 30

Comment: It seems that it started to happen recently. And I've found that the error appears when you create a new AVD, but not if you already had one from earlier. I tried with the canary of Android Studio 3.6 and the same happens.

Comment: no updates yet ?

Comment: @Andrew, what is the API+ABI you are using? I've found this same issues using arm* emulators on an x86 machine. x86 emulators work fine.

Answer (score 3):

After comparing the previous emulator version files and the latest version, turns out that the new update has added Qt5webengine to the emulator. that may be the root of this problem. submit a bug report from inside android studio and it will hopefully be fixed by the upcoming updates.

EDIT : The issue has been resolved with the latest Emulator update 29.2.11.

Answer (score 1):

Wiping device data solved it for me (Tools -> AVD Manager-> Actions column -> Wipe Data)

edit: on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Wiping the data and even recreating the virtual device did not solve the problem. After restarting Android Studio everything worked fine again